# Install php finfo on windows not working

Tags: php

i have followed the instructions when executing this code:

```
$filename = "http://localhost/__MODULES/_TRYES/logo4w.pdf";
  echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
```

i get the following error:

```
    Warning: finfo_file() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\__MODULES\_TRYES\try_10.php on line 13
```

also when viewing phpinfo() i get the following alert message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpmZ4.jpg

i am running php 5.3.5

Answer (score 0):

The php mime module is older than the php version you have. Get a newer mime module or just update the whole php stack if it's possible.

Does the url TRYES/logo4w.pdf">http://localhost/_MODULES/_TRYES/logo4w.pdf work in a browser?

Do you have in your code

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

before $filename=?

Here is a pre-made function for what you need

```
function getUrlMimeType($url) {
    $buffer = file_get_contents($url);
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    return $finfo->buffer($buffer);
}
```

Comment: i updated php but now i get this error: 
Notice: finfo_open(): Warning: string extension `B' invalid in C:\xampp\htdocs\__MODULES\_TRYES\try_10.php on line 7

Comment: Can you post the whole file on pastebin or here?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LzxCsDMh
the link to the the pdf file works on the address bar.

Comment: You have an error on try_10.php on line 7, but what you have posted is only 3 lines long.

Comment: if you could explain a bit more please, i don't understand.